# iOS add button to right side of UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a table view and would like one section's header to have a right aligned button. Ideally I could add the button to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` so as to get its header font type, size and color. In my `tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)` I've tried creating a `UIButton` and adding it to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`'s subview and content view but it does't appear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift 4.

This places a UIButton in the right lower corner of the first section using willDisplayHeaderView delegate method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview is UIButton {
           subview.removeFromSuperview()
       }
    }

    if section==0 {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.setTitle("Button title", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(button)
        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
  print("Button tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This it worked like a charm for me,

I have added **UIButton** in willDisplayHeaderView delegate method,

1) **Add Button**

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
      UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [header addSubview:button];
      [button setFrame:CGRectMake(200, -10, 300, 44)];
      [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:35]];
      [button setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addbuttonclicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; }
```

2) **Add Button Action**

```
  -(void)addbuttonclicked
   {
     //Add code     
   }
```

Hope this is help for some one .